# Unable to import material-components-web using Webpack 2

Tags: sass, webpack, webpack-2, material-components

I'm struggling to implement `material-components-web` in a React application properly with Webpack 2. I want to import the Sass files so they can be themed.

Here's what I think are relevant parts of my config:

```
var webpackConfig = module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
  entry: {
    'main': [
      './src/theme/main.scss',
      './src/client.js'
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          }, {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 3,
              sourceMap: true,
              localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          }, {
            loader: 'autoprefixer-loader',
            options: {
              browsers: 'last 2 version'
            }
          }, {
            loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
          }, {
            loader: 'sass-loader', // compiles Sass to CSS
            options: {
              outputStyle: 'expanded',
              sourceMap: true,
              includePaths: ['../src', '../node_modules', '../node_modules/@material/*']
                .map(d => path.join(__dirname, d))
                .map(g => glob.sync(g))
                .reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c), [])
            }
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'src',
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['.json', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
  }
};
```

and I start my main.scss with this:

```
$mdc-theme-primary: #4a90e2;
$mdc-theme-accent: #f22745;
$mdc-theme-background: #fff;
@import '~material-components-web/material-components-web.scss';
```

All my app Sass files load fine, but the `material-components-web` import doesn't seem to work at all but also doesn't throw any errors.

If I add `'material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.css'` to `entry.main` then it works but then I'm obviously unable to change the theme as easily so that seems wrong. What should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the latest documentation about importing the default theme here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/theming.md#step-3-changing-the-theme-with-sass
I followed 100% and it works for me using React to, according to this you probably want to change the line

```
@import '~material-components-web/material-components-web.scss';
```

to

```
@import "material-components-web/material-components-web";
```

and webpack 2 should be able to handle it.
Let us know if you found a solution.